# LAPACKE_dposv access violation with standard example

Tags: intel-mkl

I'm maintaining a project that uses the Intel MKL.

In investigating a problem I've gone back to fundamentals and started from a [standard example](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-lapack-examples/top/lapack-routines-linear-equations/posv-function/dposv-example/lapacke-dposv-example-c-row.html) for the `LAPACKE_dposv` function. I'm using it with the current version (2022.0.1) 64 bit libraries, statically linked, with the appropriate libiomp5md.dll copied to the executable directory to stop it finding a random version in the search path. Aside from fixing a trivial error in the example that was preventing compilation and (after initially discovering this issue) adding code to output the MKL version to make sure I'm using what I think I am, there are no changes from the example.

When run, the example successfully prints the version number but then generates an exception "Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF."

I've confirmed that the array pointers to the function are valid. The arrays, set up by the example, contain no NaN or Inf values.

Looking at the stack trace, the exception is being thrown in `LAPACKE_dge_nancheck()` which is buried within the MKL.

This is in Visual Studio 2019. No MKL extensions have been installed into VS to keep this clean (the original project is using an earlier version). If need be I can zip up the solution folder and put it somewhere but there isn't code I can meaningfully paste.

Is anyone familiar with this and could give a suggestion as to what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone else who is looking into this with similar issues can refer to the Intel communities for the solution as this query has been addressed here https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/LAPACKE-dposv-access-violation-with-standard-example/m-p/1384005#M33157

Comment: TLDR: the above link.  User forgot to add preprocessor directive MKL_ILP64.  This is configuration specific.